# Catching when user selects an item from a CComboBox

Tags: mfc, ccombobox

This is as basic as it gets.

I want to catch when the user selects an item from a `CComboBox` (actually, a subclass of `CComboBox`).

Tried lots of combinations of `OnCblSelChange`, `OnCommand`. Guess I haven't hit the right combo yet (no pun intended).

OS is Vista but I'm forcing an XP-style dialog (That shouldn't matter, should it?)

I'm able to catch events for classes derived from `CEdit` and `CFileDialog`.

I am at my wits end here. Any assistance would be ever-so appreciated.

Any source code would, of course, be more than ever-so appreciated.

Comment: Added code to my answer below.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, it seems that all messages (even `SELEND_OK`) for combo box changing are sent *before* the text has actually changed, so `DoDataExchange` will give you the previous text in the `CComboBox`. I have used the following method, [as suggested by MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12h9x0ch(VS.80).aspx):

```
void MyDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_COMBO_LOCATION, m_sLocation);
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MyDialog, CDialog)
    ON_CBN_SELENDOK(IDC_COMBO1, &MyDialog::OnComboChanged)
    ON_CBN_EDITUPDATE(IDC_COMBO1, &MyDialog::OnComboEdited) // This one updates immediately
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

...

void MyDialog::OnComboChanged()
{
    m_myCombo.GetLBText(m_myCombo.GetCurSel(), m_sSomeString);
}

void MyDialog::OnComboEdited()
{
    UpdateData();
}
```

It seems to work quite nicely.

Answer (score 3):

`CBN_SELENDOK` should be the message that you're looking for.  It's sent after the user selection is finalized but before the combo box closes up (if it does).  `CBN_SELCHANGE` is sent *before* the selection is actually saved to the combo box control.

[This MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12h9x0ch(VS.80).aspx) has more information (you've likely seen it already...)

Here is the code I promised you.  One thing I noticed when gathering this up is that it is possible to have this message suppressed if you are using an `ON_CONTROL_REFLECT` handler within the class derived from `CComboBox`.  This would cause the control itself to handle the message and not pass it on to the parent.  You can get around that problem by using `ON_CONTROL_REFLECT_EX` with the proper return code, which will make both the box itself and the parent receive the message.

Anyway, here's the code snippet:

```
class SPC_DOCK_CLASS ProcessingExceptionDockDlg : public CSPCDockDialog
{
    SPC_DOCK_DECLARE_SERIAL(ProcessingExceptionDockDlg);

public:
    // ... redacted ...

    //{{AFX_DATA(ProcessingExceptionDockDlg)
    CComboBox                   m_comboFilter;
    //}}AFX_DATA

    //{{AFX_VIRTUAL(ProcessingExceptionDockDlg)
    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);
    //}}AFX_VIRTUAL

protected:

    //{{AFX_MSG(ProcessingExceptionDockDlg)
    afx_msg void OnSelendokComboTreeFilter();
    //}}AFX_MSG
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

/****************/

// ProcessingExceptionDockDlg.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include "ProcessingExceptionDockDlg.h"

// ... much code redacted ...

void ProcessingExceptionDockDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CSPCDockDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    //{{AFX_DATA_MAP(ProcessingExceptionDockDlg)
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_COMBO_TREE_FILTER, m_comboFilter);
    //}}AFX_DATA_MAP
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(ProcessingExceptionDockDlg, CSPCDockDialog)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(ProcessingExceptionDockDlg)
    ON_CBN_SELENDOK(IDC_COMBO_TREE_FILTER, OnSelendokComboTreeFilter)
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void ProcessingExceptionDockDlg::OnSelendokComboTreeFilter() 
{
    // ... code redacted ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried CBN_SELENDOK but still no luck. Sure I'm missing something fundamental. Anyone out there have a code sample?

Comment: I'll try to scare one up and post it tomorrow when I get into work.

Comment: Thanx for your sample. I did not know about the DoDataExchange stuff. I tried it and still can't catch the dropdown changed/selected event(s?) but the DoDataExchange will give me additional avenues to explore. It's gotta be something dumbbutt-simple I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

Use ON_CBN_SELCHANGE on message map. it will hit when selection changed in combo box.