# Which is the event handler for Combobox for single select in MFC C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I am having trouble in enabling or disabling certain text boxes on selection of a particular combobox.

I have tried using `OnCbnSelChangeLvLayers()` & `OnCbnDropdownLvLayers()`.
The problem with the first event handler is I have to click on the same value twice and the selection in the combobox frezees. The second event handler solves the problem of freezing but I have to click on the dropdown of combobox in order for the event to occur. I also tried a few other event handlers for combobox but was not successful. `m_d_layers` is the string variable for the combobox selection (1,2,3,4)

DDX:

```
void CThermalToolDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    DDX_CBString(pDX, IDC_LV_LAYERS, m_d_lvlayers);
}
```

Message Map:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CThermalToolDlg, CDialogEx)
ON_WM_PAINT()
ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
ON_CBN_DROPDOWN(IDC_LV_LAYERS, &CThermalToolDlg::OnCbnDropdownLvLayers)
ON_CBN_DROPDOWN(IDC_HV_LAYERS, &CThermalToolDlg::OnCbnDropdownHvLayers)
ON_CBN_DROPDOWN(IDC_LVDUCTTYPE1, &CThermalToolDlg::OnCbnDropdownLvducttype1)
ON_CBN_DROPDOWN(IDC_LVDUCTTYPE2, &CThermalToolDlg::OnCbnDropdownLvducttype2)
ON_CBN_DROPDOWN(IDC_LVDUCTTYPE3, &CThermalToolDlg::OnCbnDropdownLvducttype3)
ON_CBN_DROPDOWN(IDC_HVDUCTTYPE1, &CThermalToolDlg::OnCbnDropdownHvducttype1)
ON_CBN_DROPDOWN(IDC_HVDUCTTYPE2, &CThermalToolDlg::OnCbnDropdownHvducttype2)
ON_CBN_DROPDOWN(IDC_HVDUCTTYPE3, &CThermalToolDlg::OnCbnDropdownHvducttype3)
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDCANCEL, &CThermalToolDlg::OnBnClickedCancel)
ON_BN_CLICKED(ID_CALCULATE, &CThermalToolDlg::OnCalculate)
//ON_CBN_EDITUPDATE(IDC_LV_LAYERS,&CThermalToolDlg::OnCbnEditupdateLvLayers)
//ON_CBN_SELENDOK(IDC_LV_LAYERS, &CThermalToolDlg::OnCbnSelendokLvLayers)

END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Event Handler:

```
void CThermalToolDlg::OnCbnDropdownLvLayers()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    UpdateData();

    if (m_d_lvlayers == "1")
    {
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_CU)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_ICI)->EnableWindow(0);
            //and so on
    }
    else if (m_d_lvlayers == "2")
    {
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_CU)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_ICI)->EnableWindow(1);
            //and so on

    }
    else if (m_d_lvlayers == "3")
    {
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_CU)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_ICI)->EnableWindow(1);
            //and so on
    }
    else
    {
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_CU)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_ICI)->EnableWindow(1);
            //and so on
    }
}
```

I want to obtain the desired enabling/disabling in a single click without freezing of the combobox. Is there any other way or faster method for the same?

Comment: how about the 1st answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698910/catching-when-user-selects-an-item-from-a-ccombobox  ?

Comment: @SamiSallinen Thanks for guiding me towards the question. It aligns with my question, however the solution of the two event handlers (SELENDOK & EDITUPDATE) is not working and the code jumps to else loop always. I dont know what I may be doing wrong.

Comment: Your code is terrible: the only case that is different from all others is the case "1". That being said: you need to add a picture that show what controls IDC_LV2_CU and IDC_LV2_ICI are.

Comment: @Jabberwocky The cases are different I have just not mentioned all the conditions. IDC_LV2_CU and IDC_LV2_ICI are few of the textboxes (there are many more) which need to be enabled or disabled according to 4 selections. The issue here is updating the value of combobox in the class file in a single click.

Comment: Show your message map (`BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP...`) as well as the definition for `CThermalToolDlg::DoDataExchange`. If you have `OnCbnEditUpdate` and other combobox related handler then show their definition as well. Usually you just need to handle `ON_CBN_SELCHANGE`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Edited my code. I havent used  `OnCbnEditUpdate` in my code apart from where solution was mentioned by @SamiSallinen in the first comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @BarmakShemirani I used his code of retrieving the correct string instead of `UpdateData()` in `ON_CBN_SELENDOK` event handler and now it works like a charm

DDX:

```
void CThermalToolDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
  DDX_CBString(pDX, IDC_LV_LAYERS, m_d_lvlayers);
}
```

Message Map:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CThermalToolDlg, CDialogEx)
ON_WM_PAINT()
ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
ON_CBN_SELENDOK(IDC_LV_LAYERS, &CThermalToolDlg::OnCbnSelendokLvLayers)
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDCANCEL, &CThermalToolDlg::OnBnClickedCancel)
ON_BN_CLICKED(ID_CALCULATE, &CThermalToolDlg::OnCalculate)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Event Handler:

```
void CThermalToolDlg::OnCbnSelendokLvLayers()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    CComboBox *cb = (CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_LV_LAYERS);
    if (cb)
    {
        int sel = cb->GetCurSel();
        if (sel >= 0)
            cb->GetLBText(sel, m_d_lvlayers);
    }
    TRACE(_T("[%s]\n"), m_d_lvlayers.GetString());

    /*UpdateData();*/

    if (m_d_lvlayers == "1")
    {
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_CU)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_ICI)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_PC)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_RESIN)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_RESO)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_INST)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_CU)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_ICI)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_PC)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_RESIN)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_RESO)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_INST)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV4_CU)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV4_ICI)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV4_PC)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV4_RESIN)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV4_RESO)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV4_INST)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LVDUCTTYPE1)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LVDUCTTYPE2)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LVDUCTTYPE3)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV_D_NO_12)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV_D_NO_23)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV_D_NO_34)->EnableWindow(0);
    }
    else if (m_d_lvlayers == "2")
    {
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_CU)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_ICI)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_PC)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_RESIN)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_RESO)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_INST)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_CU)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_ICI)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_PC)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_RESIN)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_RESO)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_INST)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV4_CU)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV4_ICI)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV4_PC)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV4_RESIN)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV4_RESO)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV4_INST)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LVDUCTTYPE1)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LVDUCTTYPE2)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LVDUCTTYPE3)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV_D_NO_12)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV_D_NO_23)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV_D_NO_34)->EnableWindow(0);
    }
    else if (m_d_lvlayers == "3")
    {
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_CU)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_ICI)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_PC)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_RESIN)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_RESO)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_INST)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_CU)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_ICI)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_PC)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_RESIN)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_RESO)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_INST)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV4_CU)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV4_ICI)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV4_PC)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV4_RESIN)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV4_RESO)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV4_INST)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LVDUCTTYPE1)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LVDUCTTYPE2)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LVDUCTTYPE3)->EnableWindow(0);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV_D_NO_12)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV_D_NO_23)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV_D_NO_34)->EnableWindow(0);
    }
    else
    {
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_CU)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_ICI)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_PC)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_RESIN)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_RESO)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV2_INST)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_CU)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_ICI)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_PC)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_RESIN)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_RESO)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_INST)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV4_CU)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV4_ICI)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV4_PC)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV4_RESIN)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV4_RESO)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV4_INST)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LVDUCTTYPE1)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LVDUCTTYPE2)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LVDUCTTYPE3)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV_D_NO_12)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV_D_NO_23)->EnableWindow(1);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV_D_NO_34)->EnableWindow(1);
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug for drop-list combobox and simple combobox (not drop-down). `DDX_CBString` or `DDX_CBStringExact` do not retrieve the right value in response to `ON_CBN_DROPDOWN`.

You can use your own code to retrieve the correct string:

```
void CThermalToolDlg::OnCbnDropdownLvLayers() 
{ 
    //UpdateData();
    CComboBox *cb = (CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_LV_LAYERS);
    if(cb)
    {
        int sel = cb->GetCurSel();
        if(sel >= 0)
            cb->GetLBText(sel, m_d_lvlayers);
    }
    TRACE(L"%s\n", m_d_lvlayers.GetString());
}
```

For debugging purposes, comment out other messages except `ON_CBN_DROPDOWN(IDC_LV_LAYERS...)`. Make sure you have the correct string before proceeding any further.

Do not call `UpdateData(FALSE)` as you have done in your previous question. This can cause problems specially if the correct string is not being retrieved.

Comment: This is a correct method to retrieve the correct string, but still on the selection of a value in combobox debugs to the else loop in `void CThermalToolDlg::OnCbnDropdownLvLayers()` Should I add a seperate event handler for conditions?

Comment: I am not sure about the underlying problem. Maybe there is a blank space somewhere. Put `TRACE(_T("[%s]\n"), m_d_lvlayers.GetString())`. What debug output do you see?

Comment: The underlying problem here is the event handler. `ON_CBN_DROPDOWN` event handler starts when the dropdown is clicked before making the selection. Hence I need to click on the dropdown once again after making the selection so that the value is updated. Similarly for `ON_CBN_SELCHANGE` the selection has to be made twice, but the combobox freezes here.

Comment: Use `ON_CBN_SELENDOK` instead of `ON_CBN_DROPDOWN`, and don't call `UpdateData` if it's a drop-list or simple combobox.