# CComboBox event for making selection by enter key?

Tags: user-interface, mfc, ccombobox

I have a dialog with a `CComboBox` in the DropList style.  I want it to call my function (e.g. `LoadData()`) when:

1. user clicks an item in the drop list, or
2. an item in the drop list is highlighted (either by mouse hover or keyboard), and user presses enter

but NOT when the user is still typing text in #2.

Calling `LoadData()` in the `ON_CBN_SELCHANGE` handler works fine for #1, but for #2 this event fires on every keystroke instead of only on enter. In other words, if I have combobox items:

```
1
12
123
```

and I type `12`, it will trigger `ON_CBN_SELCHANGE` once for `1`, once for `12` ... but really I'm trying to type `123`, so I don't want those first 2 keystrokes to result in `LoadData()` calls.

What's the correct way to implement this?

Comment: `ON_CBN_SELENDOK`

Comment: That's exactly it! thanks! 
Could you make this an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catching when user selects an item from a CComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698910/catching-when-user-selects-an-item-from-a-ccombobox)

Comment: @zett42 Interestingly, the top answer there adds some interaction with a CEdit which is not needed in my case.  I'm guessing their combobox uses the dropdown style, while mine uses drop list.  Does this count as a duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to the comments in your question, here is the answer:

- Right-click the control and select **Add Event Handler**:

[image: 1]

- Select the dialog class, choose the message `CBN_SELENDOK` (and adjust the method name if you want to):

[image: 2]

- This will add default event handler for you:

```
    void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnCbnSelendokCombo1()
    {
        // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    }
```

Now you can proceed as required.

---

## Alternative

- Select the control and then look at the properties pane. Click on **Control Events**:

[image: 3]

- Locate `CBN_SELENDOK` in the list, click the drop-down arrow and select the option to add the handler:

[image: 4]